# Content read incorrectly by Apache PdfBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I'm using the following code to read a pdf

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(url.openStream());
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
EarningsData earningsData = new EarningsData();
PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

String pdfText = tStripper.getText(document);
document.close();
```

When I read the pdf at https://archives.nseindia.com/corporate/OutcomeofBoardMeeting_26052023152439.pdf that contains the row

> 31.03.2023      31.12.2022      31.03.2022      31.03.2023      31.03.2022

It is actually getting read as

> 31.03.2023 3 1.12.2022 31.03.2022 g 1.03.2 023 | 3 1.03.2 022

In fact the same issue is seen if I copy and paste the row from the pdf to an editor, so it is not a bug due to Apache PdfBox but still I need to know how to correctly read the text. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just like @KJ says, the document is scanned, OCR has been applied, and the resulting text has been added in invisible text drawing instructions. The PDFBox text strippers extract the text drawn by those instructions. Thus, if you want improved text extraction, improve the quality of the OCR'ed data in the PDF (but doing OCR you can also immediately take the OCR output...).

Comment: How do I do my own OCR on the pdf?